# Building xar source error: no libcrypto?

Tags: openssl

I am building xar from source (https://github.com/mackyle/xar). It complains that I don't have OpenSSL, but I have it (my system have the openssl package installed and I have libcrypto.so.1.1.1 file in my lib directory).

Below are error messages from ./configure command when building xar:

```
...
checking for OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: Cannot build without libcrypto (OpenSSL)
...
```

What's the problem with my openssl libraries?

Comment: The issue is likely that the code you are trying to build is at least 6 years old, and uses the deprecated OpenSSL 1.0 API - see for example [OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers.html) and [OpenSSL 1.1.0 Changes](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes)

Answer (score 10):

There is a fix for this now, it only requires some small changes. You can read about it in the [Github issue](https://github.com/mackyle/xar/issues/18).

Here's what you need to do:
In `configure.ac`, line 332 is:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([crypto], [OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers], , [have_libcrypto="0"])
```

Replace it with:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([crypto], [OPENSSL_init_crypto], , [have_libcrypto="0"])
```

Note that the only change is to the second part in brackets. You can see an example of this change [here](https://github.com/VantaInc/xar/commit/bab8837fd993385115d58763e15487dc8cc13f97).

Then run `./autogen.sh`. After that you can continue install with `make` and `sudo make install`.

Comment: Note the case change from `OpenSSL_...` to `OPENSSL_...` - that bit's easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compile it, then in this particular case you need to install  `libssl1.0-dev` package.

Please note that on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you can't install both `libssl-dev` and `libssl1.0-dev` in the same time:

```
$ sudo apt install libssl-dev libssl1.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev but 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.2 is to be installed
 libssl1.0-dev : Conflicts: libssl-dev but 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: The link you mentioned is a pre-bootstraped, it's not a binary.  That's why I was building it.  Glad to know the issue is because I need a lower verion of libssl-dev.  Do you have experience that whether is it safe to have two version of libraries on my single system? Thanks.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS `libssl-dev` and `libssl1.0-dev` can not net be installed in the same time. Removed link to the "binary" release.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to build there are additional *-dev packages needed. Probably `libssl-dev` in this case.

Comment: Just installed the libssl-dev, but still the same error when running ./configure

Answer (score 0):

Install `libssl1.0-dev`

```
sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
```

Output after creating configs :

```
checking for openssl/evp.h... yes
checking for OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers in -lcrypto... yes
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for deflate in -lz... yes
checking bzlib.h usability... no
checking bzlib.h presence... no
checking for bzlib.h... no
checking for BZ2_bzCompress in -lbz2... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating cfgoutputs.stamp
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating include/xar.h
config.status: creating lib/Makefile.inc
config.status: creating lib/libxar.la.in
config.status: creating src/Makefile.inc
config.status: creating xar.spec
config.status: creating cfghdrs.stamp
config.status: creating include/config.h
```